# C# lambda function can't find json files in the project

Tags: c#, aws-lambda

My lambda function uses a json credentials file (./credentials/myfile.json).
Everything is working well on my computer or on lambdar test environment, but when I deploy it to AWS, it is enable to find the file, no matter its location.

Right now my files tree is:

myFunction

- Credentials

  - backupuser_OAuth2_Credentials.json
  - origin_GDrive_Credentials.json
- Utilities

  - GoogleDriveUtilities.cs
- Function.cs
- myFunction.csproj

And I am trying to access the credentials this way:

In Function.cs:

```
string originCredentialPath = "./Credentials/origin_GDrive_Credentials.json";

GoogleDriveUtilities origin_gdu = new GoogleDriveUtilities(originCredentialPath, "Origin account", 0);
```

In my Utility class:

```
        string[] scopes = new string[]
        {
            //GDrive access
            DriveService.Scope.Drive,
        };

        GoogleCredential credential;

        try
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(credentialPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                    .CreateScoped(DriveService.Scope.Drive);
            }

            driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = applicationName,
            });

            Console.WriteLine("Google Drive service created: " + this.serviceName + ".");
            return driveService;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error when creating Google Drive service:\n >>" + e);
        }
        return null;
```

On execution, I have the following error in cloudwatch logs:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/var/task/Credentials/origin_GDrive_Credentials.json'.
```

Any clues?

Thank you!

Comment: The path in your question is `"./Credentials/origin_GDrive_Credentials.json"` but you say the files in the Credentials folder are `file1.json` and `file2.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed the issue by using AWS Secrets, in place of using files.

As I was not able to find a way to give my lambda access to local files, I stored the json (credential informations) in AWS Secrets.

I get the json data as below:

```
string secretName = secretId;
string region = "eu-west-3";

IAmazonSecretsManager client = new AmazonSecretsManagerClient(RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(region));

GetSecretValueRequest request = new GetSecretValueRequest
{
      SecretId = secretName,
      VersionStage = "AWSCURRENT",
};

GetSecretValueResponse response;

try
{
      response = await client.GetSecretValueAsync(request);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
      throw e;
}

var originCredentialJson = response.SecretString;
```

I then accessed these data programmatically and updated my connection method as below:

```
public DriveService initDriveServiceAccount(string json)
        {
            string[] scopes = new string[]
            {
                //GDrive access
                DriveService.Scope.Drive,
            };

            GoogleCredential credential;

            try
            {
                credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(json).CreateScoped(DriveService.Scope.Drive);

                driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = applicationName,
                });

                context.Logger.LogInformation("Google Drive service created: " + this.serviceName + ".");
                return driveService;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                context.Logger.LogInformation("Error when creating Google Drive service:\n >>" + e);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).